# How can I measure how long a function runs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, profiler

I have a Matlab program that is running longer than I'd like it to.  Is there built-in way to profile Matlab, similar to how `time` works in unix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways:

- [Tic/toc](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk_r13/help/techdoc/ref/tic.html)
- [timeit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798), a fancier version of tic/toc
- [Profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html) (Desktop->Profiler in the Matlab Window)

The profiler allows you to see how much time each line takes, and thus, it is the best way to find bottlenecks.